# Intellisense no funciona

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode

Nose por que pero Intellisense no funciona a la hora de trabajar con Typescript o JavaScript.

Partiendo de eso, debo decir que nose si debo configurar el archivo **tsconfig.json** o **jsconfig.json**, os enseño la mía ya que es lo unico que he configurado (con la configuracion recomendada de la pagina de Typescript oficial):

Archivo tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/recommended/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Recommended"
}
```

Comment: qué significa que no funciona? no te marca los errores? no sugiere autocompletes? no autoimporta los exports de otros scripts?

Comment: exacto no marca nada